# Video Format Compatibility with GoPro cine studio

Tags: video

Can a video recorded using Edmund optics camera in mp4 format be played and edited in GoPro studio? The video I have recorded can not be imported.

Answer (score 1):

GoPro Studio allows constant frame rate H.264 .mp4 and .mov files. Your camera might use a variable bitrate which doesn't seem to be supported by GoPro Studio ([Source](http://gopro.com/software-app/gopro-studio-edit-software#features)).

You can transcode the video to a constant frame rate video by using the tool [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) and choosing a constant frame rate in the "Video" tab. Choose the "High Profile" preset for a good quality encoding or choose your own quality settings.

You might also want to force a certain framerate that comes close to your average frame rate instead of using "Same as source" if Handbrake makes a automated decision.

[image]